# Iterating pixels vertically from HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to find the first vertical and horizontal row in in image that has data in it.

I have got the first horizontal row easily, as when calling `getImageData`, the resulting array of pixel data is stored horizontally row-by-row. I have this data like so:

```
var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;
var heightFirst = 0;

for (var r = 0; r <= data.length; r += 4) {
    if (data[r + 3] > 0) {
        var y = (r / width) / 4;
        heightFirst = y;
        break;
    }
}
```

I now need to iterate the data vertically. I realise this is probably done using a nested for loop and doing something like this:

```
for (var r = 0; r <= data.length; r += 4) {
    for (var c = 0; c < canvasHeight; c++) {    
        if (data[(r + 3) + (c * width)] > 0) {

        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure of the exact implementation / calculation can anyone help me out??

**EDIT**

As @bobbybee and @danielpolencic have mentioned, a loop that increments by 4 * width will increment a vertical column:

```
for (var r = 0; r <= data.length; r += (4 * width)) {
  if (data[r + 3] > 0) {
    // do whatever
  }
}
```

However, this only gets information for the very first column of pixels. The next step I suppose is to repeat the loop above, but increment it by the number of columns (multiplied by 4 due to the colour data) with a loop like this:

```
for (var c = 0; c < canvas.width; c ++) {
    for (var r = 0; r <= data.length; r += ((4 * canvas.width) + (c * 4))) {
        if (data[r + 3] > 0) {
            firstX = c;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be quite right. I've stuck this on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vFz4F/2/), as you can see it should be returning 10, as this is the first column from the left, but it is writing 99 to the log. Feel like I am so close!

Comment: Rather than adding 4 each time, add 4 * width. Then use that in a loop for each vertical column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it all in a single loop without having to nest at all.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/m76VL/)**

```
var minX = canvas.width,
    minY = canvas.height;

for (var p = 0; p <= data.length; p += 4) {
     var curX = (p / 4) % canvas.width,
         curY = ((p / 4) - curX) / canvas.width;

    /* if what we're checking is higher than our recorded minX and 
      minY skip to the next row */

    if(curX > minX && curY > minY){
        // if minY is greater than 0 continue, if its 0 it can be no less so break.
        if(minY > 0){
            p=(curY+1)*(canvas.width*4); 
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }

    if (data[p + 3] > 0) {
        if (curX < minX) {
            minX = curX;
        };

        if (curY < minY) {
            minY = curY;
        };
    }
}
```

The following is the formula for getting the x and y from a single dimension array

```
X = Index % Width

Y = (Index - x) / Width
```

In our case since we are working with pixel data that is seperated into 4 component values (r/g/b/alpha) we need to divide our index by 4 like I do in the demo above.

Next I use `minX` and `minY` set to the canvas width and height. Whenever we hit a pixel we check if its `x` or `y` are lower than our lowest `x` and `y` stored. If they are lower, then we keep the value and move on.

However its easier to read, and **[faster](http://jsperf.com/single-dimension-vs-multi)** to use more than one loop to read the data.

```
for (var x = 0; x <= canvas.width; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y <= canvas.height; y++) {
    if (minY < y) {
      break;
    }
    if (data[((y * canvas.width + x) * 4) + 3] > 0) {
      if (x < minX) {
        minX = x;
      }
      if (y < minY) {
        minY = y;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**[Demo to get the lastX and lastY](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/m76VL/10/)**

```
for (var x = 0; x <= canvas.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y <= canvas.height; y++) {
        if (data[((y * canvas.width + x) * 4) + 3] > 0) {
            if (x < firstX) {
                firstX = x;
            }
            if (y < firstY) {
                firstY = y;
            }

            if (x > lastX) {
                lastX = x;
            }
            if (y > lastY) {
                lastY = y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I originally did use this method. The problem with this, is that it is still going down row by row, so although the Y position will definitely be correct, the X position is only correct if the image on the canvas is a square. Check out my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vFz4F/. You can see that the first column with a coloured pixel from the left is actually 0, but this isn't being picked up.

Comment: @dormisher so if I understand it correctly you want the first column, and the first row of data occurring, but the column and row are independent of each other? Or in your data does the first column take precedence over the first row? Anyway I updated my answer. Let me know if I'm close.

Comment: Yeah independent of each other. Basically just 'which is the first vetical column from left to right which has a coloured pixel' && 'which is the first row from top to bottom which has the first coloured pixel'.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get these values independently of each other in a single loop.

Comment: @dormisher in my updated answer that's exactly what I do in a single loop. http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/m76VL/

Comment: Ahh yes very true. The thing with this, is that iterates every single pixel. If you do it in two loops, you only do it until you find a pixel, then you break. So even though it is 2 loops, in most situations it will be far quicker to actually have the 2 loops! Good solution though and it does answer my original question :)

Comment: @dormisher heh, updated again. It should be on par with a two loop solution since essentially the first condition is acting like a break. Ill write up a jsperf as well for the heck of it.

Comment: @dormisher http://jsperf.com/single-dimension-vs-multi multi loop method is faster updated my answer to reflect that as well.

Comment: Excellent stuff this dude and cheers for the jsperf. Just one more thing though I promise! I want to also get the last x & y positions, so I figured just do the same loops as above backwards. This gets the correct x position but not the correct y position. Look at this js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m76VL/9/ to see what I mean. You know why?

Comment: @dormisher haha yet another edit. I edited it with how I personally would do it. You lose the ability to break out of the loop, but you are saving yourself from having to loop over everything *potentially* twice. For example imagine if your box was at 98,98, with a width and height of 2. The first instance you would have have to run the entire loop to get the min, and then again for a small portion to get the max.

Answer (score 1):

Like @bobbybee correctly pointed out, the step for your loop is `4 * image_width`.

```
for (var r = 0; r <= data.length; r += (4 * width)) {
    for (var c = 0; c < canvasHeight; c++) {
        if (data[r + 3] > 0) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is actually not far off being right, the `for (var r = 0; r <= data.length; r += (4 * width)) {` actually just iterates the first vertical column. I nearly have it I think but I'm not quite there, see my edit. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by a single loop (no need to nest loops here):

```js
for(var y = 0; y < data.length; y += canvas.width * 4) {
    if (data[y + 3] > 0 ) { /*...*/ }
}
```

or to squeeze out a little more speed:

```js
var y = 0,
    length = data.length,     /// cache length
    width = canvas.width * 4; /// cache width

while(y < length) {
    if (data[y + 3] > 0 ) { /*...*/ }
    y += width;
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work. In each iteration you are only getting a very small sample of pixels since `canvas.width * 4` would be a pretty large number.

Comment: This method only gets pixels in the first column I think, see my edit.

Comment: @dormisher That was the idea but I realize I misunderstood the iterating vertical part (I read somehow the first vertical line) :-S